# Bootstrap Btn Classes Not Working on Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, mobile

For some reason, I can't get mobile to stop applying its default styling and respect the bootstrap css (v3.4.1). Below is my html:

```
 <div class="buttons col-xs-4">
        <div id="btnvote1" class="btn-wrap row-md-4 mtop10 mbottom10">
            <button class="btn-vote btn btn-secondary" onclick="vote(1)">Opt 1</button>
        </div>
        <div id="btnvote2" class="btn-wrap row-md-4 mbottom10">
            <button class="btn-vote btn btn-primary" onclick="vote(2)">Opt 2</button>
        </div>
        <div id="btnvote3" class="btn-wrap row-md-4 mbottom10">
            <button class="btn-vote btn btn-secondary" onclick="vote(3)">Opt 3</button>
        </div>
        <div id="btnvote4" class="btn-wrap row-md-4 mbottom10">
            <button class="btn-vote btn btn-secondary" onclick="vote(4)">Opt 4</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My BundleConfig rendered in _Layout.cshtml

```
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

How it looks in Chrome on PC:

[image: How it should look]

How it looks on two different gen iPhones (5s, 6) in Chrome:

[image]

What the internet keeps telling me should work, but I'm having no luck:

```
button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated

**EDIT:**

**Soltuion**

It appears the problem was assuming `btn-secondary` was a class provided by bootstrap. What I was actually seeing was Buttons.Less providing some styling (i.e. grey button background). Buttons.Less also sets the webkit appearance to button, which I think was causing mobile to override to mobile default and not display the styling (as seen above, it ignoring the grey button background).

If I use one of the Bootstrap v3 btn classes, it yields the desired results on mobile

```
.btn
.btn-default
.btn-primary
.btn-success
.btn-info
.btn-warning
.btn-danger
.btn-link
```

The reason why everyone's fiddle examples worked, is because they were using bootstrap v4, which includes a `btn-secondary` class.

Comment: What all styles do you see being applied to the buttons when you inspect them using Chrome Dev Tools? It's my understanding you shouldn't have to apply those appearance properties. My guess is some other CSS somewhere is overriding the bootstrap styling for buttons. Can you emulate this issue on a JSFiddle and pure HTML/CSS/JS?

Comment: Can you post a working example? If I try to recreate this with your code, it works just fine.

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate using just JSFiddle. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/4v1nhLr3/) looks fine on my mobile testing devices. I'm wondering if rendering the bundle config with cshtml is causing issues on mobile. Unfortunately, since I only have iPhones to test with, I'm fairly gated on inspecting source.

Comment: Might be some issue in your custom styles. I have try with [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/hardyrajput/7L3vsyad/1/). It's working fine in Iphone 5s and 7+.

Comment: check any other btn class overriding or not. if u r performing onclick operation then use a tag and give btn class role=button to them

Comment: If you only have access to devices, you should be able to do some debugging (it is possible to debug an android phone from a windows machine in Chrome; and an iphone from a mac/safari). Really, being able to see what CSS is being applied (or not applied, or overwritten) is the only way you're going to get a definitive answer.
Other than that, I'd check that the CSS bundle actually has the styles for the buttons in it. I've run into .Net bundling having issue with bootstrap before.

Comment: I know the CSS is being bundled as it applies the styling correctly when I run it on chrome through my PC. Edited to clarify this as it keeps getting missed.

The fiddles also look fine on my mobile. Something, on my basic site (it's almost entirely just what you start with when starting a visual studios web MVC + Asp .Net project), is causing mobile to think it needs to eliminate/override bootstrap css. So it's not inherently the styling.

To your debugging point, I do not have a mac, so I'm not sure if I can debug my iPhones. I have no android phones to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are couple of mistakes in your code and expectation

1. .btn-secondary class is not in the Bootstrap 3, You need to use Bootstrap v4 for that
2. The button style which you have mentioned is of .btn-primary class not .btn-secondary class.

So replace the .btn-Secondary class to .btn-primary class,
then this code will work fine.

```
button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be, at least, partially the problem. Buttons.less is providing the css I'm using that you can see on PC (as seen in OP), but not showing on mobile. However, if I use different btn classes for Bootstrap 3 (primary, warning, etc.) it yields some results.. I don't quite understand this and will have to investigate further - will edit this post.

Comment: Because .secondary is of bootstrap 4 class which have grey color which is exactly similar to the default style. And the button which you have mentioned is primary.